# Codename One - Facebook Marketing API

Tags: facebook, codenameone

I was looking for a way to integrate my CodenameOne app with Facebook. Particularly to collect data aimed to improve the adds shown on Facebook to users who have, for example, installed the app. What I found for integration with Facebook on CN1 is (mainly) this https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/social/FacebookConnect.html
This seems useful for publishing photos or posts to Facebook as a user, but not for gathering data as I need it. Is there a way to access this part of the Facebook SDK in CN1? If there isn´t is this planned for the future?

Comment: What data would you gather?

Comment: They weren´t really specific on this, but probably installations and some events like registering ownership of a specific product.

Comment: What would you use Facebook for?

Comment: As said in the question, to show specific adds to them ON Facebook, I suppose that count as using Facebook doesn´t it? (and tovisualize the data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connect API is designed for authorization and authentication which need to be native. From that point on you can use the token against the standard Facebook Graph API.

I'm not really familiar with the marketing API but does it require functionality from the native SDK which isn't available in the current SDK?

Comment: From what I have seen on the fb docs, I have to either use the SDK or use this API https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/app-event-api/v2.6. For the first it usually has some initialization method and then a logger to register app events, (like level up, registration complete and others). The second works by sending http calls but needs the developer to get the Apple's Advertising Identifier (IDFA) or Android's Advertising ID.

Comment: Those are things we don't expose at this moment but you can probably access them relatively easily with native interfaces.